# Menu to control stops on Bing map

Tags: jquery, menu, maps, bing

I have a Bing map with 2000+ stops indicated on the map via map icons. I want to have a two-level menu to the right of the map that allows the user to uncheck a box and all the map icons associated with either level one or level two disappear from the map.

I place my lat lon information into variables:

```
{ 'lat': 33.62884998, 'lng': -84.29331064, 'state': 'X', 'title': 'Route 
01', 'description': 'here','icon' 
:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-pushpin.png' },
{ 'lat': 32.88286, 'lng': -83.76431, 'state': 'X2', 'title': 'Route 02', 
'description': 'there','icon' 
:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/pink-pushpin.png' },
```

And then I use functions to gather the list:

```
   $(function () {

        var uniqueStates = [];

        initialData.forEach(function (ele) {
            ele.visible = true; // add visible property to all pushPinData entries, set to true

            if (!uniqueStates.some(v => v == ele.state)) {  //add this state to the list of unique states if not already there
                uniqueStates.push(ele.state);
            }

        });

        uniqueStates.forEach(state => { //iterate through unique states
            $("#controls").append("<div style=\"margin-top:0.5em;margin-bottom:0.5em\">");  //add dive to separate out groups by state
            $("#controls").append("<div><label><input class=\"state-cb\" type=\"checkbox\"  data-state=\"" + state + "\" checked>" + state + "</label></div>"); // add checkbox for specific state

            var stateRoutes = initialData.filter(pin => {  //get from pushPinInfos where the state matches the current state

             return pin.state == state;

            });

            var uniqueStateRoutes = [];

            stateRoutes.forEach(rte => {    //iterate through routes for this state, from earlier
                if (!uniqueStateRoutes.some(v => v == rte.title)) { //if unique route for state is not already in array, add it
                    uniqueStateRoutes.push(rte.title);
                } 
            });

            uniqueStateRoutes.forEach(uniqueRte => {    //for each unique state, add a checkbox
                $("#controls").append("<div><label><input id=\"" + state + uniqueRte + "\" class=\"route-cb " + uniqueRte + " " + state + "\" style=\"margin-left:1em\" type=\"checkbox\"  data-state=\"" + state + "\"  data-route=\"" + uniqueRte + "\" checked>" + uniqueRte + "</label></div>")

            });

            $("#controls").append("</div>"); //close div from earlier

        });


        $(".state-cb").change(function () { //bind state checkbox change handler

            var checked = $(this).prop("checked");  
            var state = $(this).data("state");  
            $("." + state).prop("checked", checked);    //select all checkboxes with same state class and set them checked or not.

        });

        $("#refresh").click(function () {   //bind refresh button event handler

            initialData.forEach(ele => {
                var checked = $(".route-cb[data-route='" + ele.title + "'][data-state='" + ele.state + "']").prop("checked") ;//get whether related checkbox is checked
                ele.visible = checked;
            });
            RefreshMap();

        });

    });
            CollapsibleLists.applyTo(document.getElementById('state'));
    function RefreshMap() {
        var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        var apiKey = "KEY HERE";
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { credentials: apiKey });
        // Create the info box for the pushpin
        pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false });
        infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);
        var locs = [];

        var data = initialData;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var currentPushpin = data[i];

            if (currentPushpin.visible) {

                locs[i] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(currentPushpin.lat, currentPushpin.lng);
                var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(locs[i], { icon: currentPushpin.icon, width: '20px', height: '20px' });
                pin.Title = currentPushpin.title;
                pin.Description = currentPushpin.description;
                pinLayer.push(pin);
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);
            }
        }
        map.entities.push(pinLayer);
        map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);
        var bestview = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs);
        map.setView({ center: bestview.center, zoom: 5 });
    }
```

When the page is accessed the map will appear with all the stops. The menu on the right will have the State and the Route under the State. If the user unchecks the State all routes/stops associated with that State will disappear from the map. If the user only unchecks routes only those routes and stops will disappear from the map.

And it works as it is now. However, the menu list is extremely long. It would be a much better user experience if the list collapsed to the State. How can I make that happen?

Comment: Are the stops not already grouped by state?

Comment: no, each stop is a variable